# How to model a switch-like event?

Tags: python, aimms

How can you model a switch-like scenario.
For example you have a light bulb that is turned on if the value is 1 and off when 0. You can turn it on for a period of time then turn it off. So the result for example would be, for t=10, 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 if we choose to open the bulb at t=4 and close it at t=9.
So we create a binary variable, switch_var(t), with t as time to represent the state of the bulb whether on or off.
Then we add a single instance event of opening the light bulb and another for closing the light bulb.
Let open(t), for when we open the light bulb, and close(t), for when we close the light bulb, be a binary variable.
Assume that the bulb is off at its initial state so switch_var(0) = 0.

Model:

switch_var(t) <= switch_var(t-1) + open(t) - close(t)

#we use the previous state then add 1 when opened and minus 1 when closed.
sum

sum[t, open(t)] <= 1
sum[t, close(t)] <= 1

#to ensure that opening and closing are a one time event.

If bulb is on at initial state, switch_var(0) = 1

and we remove open(t) from the model.

switch_var(t) <= switch_var(t-1) - close(t)

sum[t, close(t)] <= 1

How can you model this differently without using a previous state like switch_var(t-1). Is it possible?

The previous model creates a lot of problem. Like if t starts at 1 and not t=0, you have to use an if function since switch_var(t-1) will be switch_var(0). Can it be modeled without using t-1? And what if the bulb was open in its initial state?

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. 
The code should be formatted as code. Like this it's very hard to read.

Comment: Related to your question/model. 
1. Your model is in pseudo-code now. I see you tagged python, but the model you presented is not coded in python yet. 
2. Why you don't want to use an `if` statement within your model? 
3. Why open/close functions have to be binary lists of the same length of `t`? Do you know in advance at what `t` you are going to open/close the bulb? In that case open/close can simply be integers that correspond to the value of `t` for which the bulb is opened/closed. 
4. However you structure your model, you would still have to define an initial state (open/closed)

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do, even some code using the "bad model" would be helpful, but from what I gather from your explanation, you need to use generators to solve your issues.